# Android Fragments - replace and add

Tags: android-fragments

I have an activity with framelayout, am adding fragment in onresume of this actvity again am replacing this fragment with other fragment, after replacing if i open any other application and after came back to my application automatically its adding first freagment. how to stop this.?

Comment: Move adding of fragment to onCreate of the activity? or save the current fragment as a boolean to the shared prefs and then in onResume check shared prefs for which fragment was loaded and load it again

Comment: Oncreate also calling but now i added null check with savedinstance in oncreate, its working

Answer (score 0):

Moving it only to onCreate and checking if save instance is not null will not fix you problem in every case, e.g. rotating device will cause adding this fragment again.

You have to check if there is already added fragment in your framelayout. To do this call:

```java
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ...;
if(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_frame_layout_id) != null) {
    //it's mean that there is no fragment in your container, add fragment
}
```